# Flutter Midtrans Payment Gateway

Tags: android, flutter, dart, payment, gateway

im trying to use this package called midtrans_sdk. It's basically a package that allowed me to use the "midtrans" payment gateway.

In the void main function of the code there's "await DotEnv.load();".

Which i can't use because it throws load function is not defined. I tried to search about it and cant seem to find other that have a problem like this.

here's the link to the package
https://pub.dev/packages/midtrans_sdk/example

Thankyou in advance.

To be honest i dont really know what does the dotenv do. all i know is its a method to load your enviroment file to get the variables. But even that, why does it said the load function is not defined

Comment: nvm, it a really dumb fix. i deleted the prefix "as DotEnv" and try calling it normally with dotenv.load and it works. just WOW

Comment: its official sdk? no? just wait until you test that sdk on production. better to use their official core api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the "As DotEnv" when importing the dotenv library and instead calling the load function DotEnv.load() just call it  with dotenv.load()and it will work.

Comment: yeah its a dumb mistake, mb. thankyou